# Direct run the product URL it redirect to cookies page first time IN Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to directly open [this url](http://sitename.com/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty;=1).

but it gets redirect to cookies page the first time, and second time works fine.

What to do so that it will run first time itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Cookie redirect in the Backoffice :

System / Configuration / General / Web / Browser Capabilities Detection / Redirect to CMS-page if cookies are disabled => No